# The best method for simple calendar?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

What is the best method for storing data in database for a simple calender?
This calender is with hours:

```
2011-12-17 | 2011-12-18 etc
00:00      | 00:00
00:30      | 00:30
01:00      | 01:00
01:30      | 01:30
etc
```

I can for each hours set TRUE or FALSE. The default is FALSE.

For each day, I can create new row in database, for example:

```
id  | day
1   | 2011-12-17
2   | 2011-12-18
etc
```

How I can I do this with hours? I would like to store in the database only days with set = TRUE. Is it possible? or I must create in database each hour?

On the page, I can generate days with loop for, but how and how can I show on this also days with TRUE on database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up my db with 3 columns, `id | day | hours` and on hours, store a serialized array of the hours.